# PHPUnit: when run in command line, display code coverage?

Tags: command-line, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm running tests PHPUnit from command line, but can't work out how to make it show the code coverage results in the terminal.

There are various [command line options here in their documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) but they all involve outputting the results to a file in one of various formats.

Am I missing an obvious solution? Or would I need to write a batch file that executes:

1. executes the PHPUnit command and flags that output code coverage to a file
2. outputs the contents of the file to stdio so it appears in the terminal

Answer (score 59, accepted):

File is not mandatory for `--coverage-text` option, you can run just

```
./phpunit.phar --coverage-text
```

and get results in the terminal.

Comment: Is there a way of gaining greater insight from --coverage-text? Eg what numbers?

Comment: @JohnHunt you can use `--coverage-html=coverage` to dump a fancy coverage report with line-by-line information.